# LazyLoading with EF and stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My EF was taking ages to execute and when using SQL Server Profiler I could see it was separating my query into little parts which were all adding up.

I decided to create a stored procedure to reduce the loading time. It looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        a.*, 
        b.*, 
        b1.*,
        c.*, 
        preview.*,
        e.*, 
        a1.*, 
        a2.*,
        a3.*,
        a4.*,
        a5.*,
        a6.*,
        a7.*,
        a8.*,
        a9.*,
        a10.*,
        a11.*,
        a12.*,
        a13.*
    FROM 
        Products AS a
    INNER JOIN 
        Details AS b ON a.DetailId = b.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        Categories AS c ON a.CategoryId = c.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        Previews AS preview ON a.PreviewId = preview.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributes AS e ON a.AttributeId = e.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributePicture AS a1 ON e.Id = a1.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeVideo AS a2 ON e.Id = a2.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeAudio AS a3 ON e.Id = a3.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeBattery AS a4 ON e.Id = a4.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeDimensions AS a5 ON e.Id = a5.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeDisplay AS a6 ON e.Id = a6.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeLightExposure AS a7 ON e.Id = a7.AttributeId 
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeFlash as a8 ON e.Id = a8.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeFocusing AS a9 ON e.Id = a9.AttributeId 
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeInterface AS a10 ON e.Id = a10.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeLens AS a11 ON e.Id = a11.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeLensZoom AS b1 ON a11.id = b1.LensId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeNetwork AS a12 ON e.Id = a12.AttributeId
    INNER JOIN 
        CameraAttributeShutter AS a13 ON e.Id = a13.AttributeId
END
GO
```

I have joined all the tables in the query hoping that they would match my model in my application:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string GTIN { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Make { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string Model { get; set; }
    public bool Expert { get; set; }
    public bool Sponsored { get; set; }

    public virtual CameraAttribute Attributes { get; set; }
    public virtual Detail Details { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Preview Preview { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, all the virtual properties are null.

I assume I can't lazy load them when using stored procedures, so how can I get the properties to be populated?

I can't post it all because it crashes the browser, but here is a snippet. I hope that helps:

```
Opened connection asynchronously at 19/04/2016 12:31:57 +01:00

'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-38-131055390555737826): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Piiick.Web'. 
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[GTIN] AS [GTIN], 
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
    [Extent1].[Make] AS [Make], 
    [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Extent1].[Expert] AS [Expert], 
    [Extent1].[Sponsored] AS [Sponsored], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent1].[DetailId] AS [DetailId], 
    [Extent1].[PreviewId] AS [PreviewId]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]


-- Executing asynchronously at 19/04/2016 12:31:57 +01:00

-- Completed in 7 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:31:57 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Join13].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Join13].[CompatibleMemory] AS [CompatibleMemory], 
    [Join13].[WhiteBalance] AS [WhiteBalance], 
    [Join13].[SceneModes] AS [SceneModes], 
    [Join13].[ShootingModes] AS [ShootingModes], 
    [Join13].[PhotoEffects] AS [PhotoEffects], 
    [Join13].[CameraPlayback] AS [CameraPlayback], 
    [Join13].[Tripod] AS [Tripod], 
    [Join13].[DirectPrinting] AS [DirectPrinting], 
    [Join13].[Colour] AS [Colour], 
    [Join13].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
    [Join13].[Id3] AS [Id2], 
    [Join13].[Id4] AS [Id3], 
    [Join13].[Id5] AS [Id4], 
    [Join13].[Id6] AS [Id5], 
    [Join13].[Id7] AS [Id6], 
    [Join13].[Id8] AS [Id7], 
    [Join13].[Id9] AS [Id8], 
    [Join13].[Id10] AS [Id9], 
    [Join13].[Id11] AS [Id10], 
    [Join13].[Id12] AS [Id11], 
    [Join13].[Id13] AS [Id12], 
    [Join13].[Id14] AS [Id13]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[CompatibleMemory] AS [CompatibleMemory], [Extent2].[WhiteBalance] AS [WhiteBalance], [Extent2].[SceneModes] AS [SceneModes], [Extent2].[ShootingModes] AS [ShootingModes], [Extent2].[PhotoEffects] AS [PhotoEffects], [Extent2].[CameraPlayback] AS [CameraPlayback], [Extent2].[Tripod] AS [Tripod], [Extent2].[DirectPrinting] AS [DirectPrinting], [Extent2].[Colour] AS [Colour], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id4], [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id5], [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id6], [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id7], [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id8], [Extent10].[Id] AS [Id9], [Extent11].[Id] AS [Id10], [Extent12].[Id] AS [Id11], [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id12], [Extent14].[Id] AS [Id13], [Extent15].[Id] AS [Id14]
        FROM              [dbo].[CameraAttributes] AS [Extent2]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeAudio] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeBattery] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent4].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeDimensions] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent5].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeDisplay] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent6].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeLightExposure] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent7].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeFlash] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent8].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeFocusing] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent9].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeInterface] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent10].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeLens] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent11].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeNetwork] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent12].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributePicture] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent13].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeShutter] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent14].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeVideo] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent15].[AttributeId] ) AS [Join13] ON [Extent1].[AttributeId] = [Join13].[Id1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 11 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[SupportedFormats] AS [SupportedFormats], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeAudio] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[PowerSource] AS [PowerSource], 
    [Extent1].[Technology] AS [Technology], 
    [Extent1].[Life] AS [Life], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeBattery] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 6 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Width] AS [Width], 
    [Extent1].[Depth] AS [Depth], 
    [Extent1].[Height] AS [Height], 
    [Extent1].[Weight] AS [Weight], 
    [Extent1].[WeightIncludingBattery] AS [WeightIncludingBattery], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeDimensions] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 3 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[Diagonal] AS [Diagonal], 
    [Extent1].[Resolution] AS [Resolution], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeDisplay] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[IsoSensitivity] AS [IsoSensitivity], 
    [Extent1].[Mode] AS [Mode], 
    [Extent1].[Correction] AS [Correction], 
    [Extent1].[Metering] AS [Metering], 
    [Extent1].[Minimum] AS [Minimum], 
    [Extent1].[Maxiumum] AS [Maxiumum], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeLightExposure] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Modes] AS [Modes], 
    [Extent1].[ExposureLock] AS [ExposureLock], 
    [Extent1].[RangeWide] AS [RangeWide], 
    [Extent1].[RangeTelephoto] AS [RangeTelephoto], 
    [Extent1].[RechargeTime] AS [RechargeTime], 
    [Extent1].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeFlash] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Focus] AS [Focus], 
    [Extent1].[Adjustment] AS [Adjustment], 
    [Extent1].[AutoFocusModes] AS [AutoFocusModes], 
    [Extent1].[ClosestDistance] AS [ClosestDistance], 
    [Extent1].[NormalRange] AS [NormalRange], 
    [Extent1].[MacroRangeTelephoto] AS [MacroRangeTelephoto], 
    [Extent1].[MacroRangeWide] AS [MacroRangeWide], 
    [Extent1].[AutoModeTelephoto] AS [AutoModeTelephoto], 
    [Extent1].[AutoModeWide] AS [AutoModeWide], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeFocusing] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[PictBridge] AS [PictBridge], 
    [Extent1].[USBVersion] AS [USBVersion], 
    [Extent1].[USBType] AS [USBType], 
    [Extent1].[HDMI] AS [HDMI], 
    [Extent1].[HDMIType] AS [HDMIType], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeInterface] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Join1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Join1].[FocalLength] AS [FocalLength], 
    [Join1].[MinimumFocalLength] AS [MinimumFocalLength], 
    [Join1].[MaximumFocalLength] AS [MaximumFocalLength], 
    [Join1].[MinimumAperture] AS [MinimumAperture], 
    [Join1].[MaximumAperture] AS [MaximumAperture], 
    [Join1].[LensStructure] AS [LensStructure], 
    [Join1].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
    [Join1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM  [dbo].[CameraAttributeLens] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[FocalLength] AS [FocalLength], [Extent2].[MinimumFocalLength] AS [MinimumFocalLength], [Extent2].[MaximumFocalLength] AS [MaximumFocalLength], [Extent2].[MinimumAperture] AS [MinimumAperture], [Extent2].[MaximumAperture] AS [MaximumAperture], [Extent2].[LensStructure] AS [LensStructure], [Extent2].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2]
        FROM  [dbo].[CameraAttributeLens] AS [Extent2]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeLensZoom] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[LensId] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[Id1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Optical] AS [Optical], 
    [Extent1].[Digital] AS [Digital], 
    [Extent1].[ExtraSmart] AS [ExtraSmart], 
    [Extent1].[Combined] AS [Combined], 
    [Extent1].[LensId] AS [LensId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeLensZoom] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[LensId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[WiFi] AS [WiFi], 
    [Extent1].[WiFiStandards] AS [WiFiStandards], 
    [Extent1].[NFC] AS [NFC], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeNetwork] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Megapixel] AS [Megapixel], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[SensorType] AS [SensorType], 
    [Extent1].[MaxResolution] AS [MaxResolution], 
    [Extent1].[Resolutions] AS [Resolutions], 
    [Extent1].[Stablizer] AS [Stablizer], 
    [Extent1].[Location] AS [Location], 
    [Extent1].[SupportedAspectRatios] AS [SupportedAspectRatios], 
    [Extent1].[TotalMegapixels] AS [TotalMegapixels], 
    [Extent1].[Formats] AS [Formats], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributePicture] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[FastestSpeed] AS [FastestSpeed], 
    [Extent1].[SlowestSpeed] AS [SlowestSpeed], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeShutter] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[MaxResolution] AS [MaxResolution], 
    [Extent1].[Resolutions] AS [Resolutions], 
    [Extent1].[CaptureResolution] AS [CaptureResolution], 
    [Extent1].[FrameRate] AS [FrameRate], 
    [Extent1].[FullHD] AS [FullHD], 
    [Extent1].[SupportedFormats] AS [SupportedFormats], 
    [Extent1].[AttributeId] AS [AttributeId]
    FROM [dbo].[CameraAttributeVideo] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent2].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
    [Extent2].[Summary] AS [Summary], 
    [Extent2].[ShortSummary] AS [ShortSummary]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Details] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[DetailId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

Opened connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Join13].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Join13].[CompatibleMemory] AS [CompatibleMemory], 
    [Join13].[WhiteBalance] AS [WhiteBalance], 
    [Join13].[SceneModes] AS [SceneModes], 
    [Join13].[ShootingModes] AS [ShootingModes], 
    [Join13].[PhotoEffects] AS [PhotoEffects], 
    [Join13].[CameraPlayback] AS [CameraPlayback], 
    [Join13].[Tripod] AS [Tripod], 
    [Join13].[DirectPrinting] AS [DirectPrinting], 
    [Join13].[Colour] AS [Colour], 
    [Join13].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
    [Join13].[Id3] AS [Id2], 
    [Join13].[Id4] AS [Id3], 
    [Join13].[Id5] AS [Id4], 
    [Join13].[Id6] AS [Id5], 
    [Join13].[Id7] AS [Id6], 
    [Join13].[Id8] AS [Id7], 
    [Join13].[Id9] AS [Id8], 
    [Join13].[Id10] AS [Id9], 
    [Join13].[Id11] AS [Id10], 
    [Join13].[Id12] AS [Id11], 
    [Join13].[Id13] AS [Id12], 
    [Join13].[Id14] AS [Id13]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[CompatibleMemory] AS [CompatibleMemory], [Extent2].[WhiteBalance] AS [WhiteBalance], [Extent2].[SceneModes] AS [SceneModes], [Extent2].[ShootingModes] AS [ShootingModes], [Extent2].[PhotoEffects] AS [PhotoEffects], [Extent2].[CameraPlayback] AS [CameraPlayback], [Extent2].[Tripod] AS [Tripod], [Extent2].[DirectPrinting] AS [DirectPrinting], [Extent2].[Colour] AS [Colour], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id4], [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id5], [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id6], [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id7], [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id8], [Extent10].[Id] AS [Id9], [Extent11].[Id] AS [Id10], [Extent12].[Id] AS [Id11], [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id12], [Extent14].[Id] AS [Id13], [Extent15].[Id] AS [Id14]
        FROM              [dbo].[CameraAttributes] AS [Extent2]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeAudio] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeBattery] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent4].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeDimensions] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent5].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeDisplay] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent6].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeLightExposure] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent7].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeFlash] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent8].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeFocusing] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent9].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeInterface] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent10].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeLens] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent11].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeNetwork] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent12].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributePicture] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent13].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeShutter] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent14].[AttributeId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CameraAttributeVideo] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent15].[AttributeId] ) AS [Join13] ON [Extent1].[AttributeId] = [Join13].[Id1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 19/04/2016 12:32:01 +01:00
```

Comment: *I could see it was separating my query into little parts which were all adding up* Or you could just, you know, use `Include`

Comment: An example would be good.

Comment: I prefer refactoring the previous query instead using SP. if you have just a performance issue, i think you can enhance the ef query, let me see your expression and after that decide what could we do

Comment: It's massive, but I will post it above.

Comment: @MahdiFarhani It would not let me post it all, so I posted what I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Eager Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) a joined entity in EF using the [`Include<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Like this:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Product
                      .Include(p => p.Category ) 
                      //more included properties
                      .Where(....) //filtering                          
                      .ToList(); //ToList() eagerly loads the Included entites
}
```

Comment: I do use Eager Loading the majority of the time, but I am unsure how that will help here as I need to return all related entities :(

Comment: You mean you don't know what relations the object has? Or are you trying to do this dynamically? Also could you try to explain why you are trying to get all related entities? As reading most of a database into EF entities is usually a bad idea..

Comment: Yeah usually it is a bad idea, but unfortunately in this case all product related fields (attributes, etc) must be returned because there is client side logic that does things based on dynamic properties.

Comment: Also have you tried disabling change tracking in the EF context? If you are just sending the data over to the client, that is a big perf improvement.